# Getting a list of American physicists from DBpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to query the [American Physicsts](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category%3aAmerican_physicists) and get the list of physicists. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

The SPARQL you need would look like this ....

```
PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?s dcterms:subject category:American_physicists .
}
```

see results [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20category:%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dcterms:%20%3Chttp://purl.org/dc/terms/%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?s%20dcterms:subject%20category:American_physicists%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&debug=on&timeout=&format=text/html&save=display&fname=)

If you want the list with some extra predicates you need to join more triple patterns using the variable `?s`. For instance, to retrieve the birthdate for each physicist ...

```
PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?s dcterms:subject category:American_physicists .
  ?s dbpedia:birthDate ?bithdate .
}
```

results [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20category:%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dcterms:%20%3Chttp://purl.org/dc/terms/%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbpedia:%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?s%20dcterms:subject%20category:American_physicists%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?s%20dbpedia:birthDate%20?bithdate%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A&debug=on&timeout=&format=text/html&save=display&fname=)